# Кнопка нажимается со второго раза

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

По нажатии на кнопку, бэкграунд в body должен менять цвет. 
Все работает сносно, кроме того, что нажимается она, почему-то, только со второго раза.

```
function ColorChange() {
if (document.body.style.backgroundColor == "black") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
} else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black"; 
}
}
```

В стилях к body следующее:

```
body{
background-color:black;
transition: all 4s;
}
```

Comment: Неа, всё правильно отрабатывает: с первого раза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё потому, что изначально у вас нет никакого цвета. Вы проверяете inline цвет.

То есть document.body.style.backgroundColor берёт цвет из `<body style`, а не из таблицы стилей. Поэтому лучше было бы сделать функцию toggleClass, но если вам всё таки надо именно стили переключать, то можно сделать проверку на наличие цвета у элемента.

```js
function ColorChange() {
var currentColor = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
alert(currentColor);
if (!currentColor || currentColor == "black") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
} else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black"; 
}
}
```

```css
body{
background-color:black;
transition: all 4s;
}
```

```html
<body>
<button onclick="ColorChange()">test</button>
</body>
```